Install certificates in MDT task sequence
I am using a deployment task sequence to call a Powershell script to install multiple certificates, but it is not installing them.
I am using the following in the Power Shell Script:
Import-Certificate -FilePath "%DeploymentRoot%\Scripts\certs\cert1.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My
Import-Certificate -FilePath "%DeploymentRoot%\Scripts\certs\cert2.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My
Import-Certificate -FilePath "%DeploymentRoot%\Scripts\certs\cert3.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My

I tested changing to the full path and installs fine on the server.
I tested the following in the PS script, but doesn't seem to work eventhough if I run the same while in the last stages of the imiagin processs does work.
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
z: 
cd Scripts\certs 
Import-Certificate -FilePath "cert1.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My

I searched the logs in folder C:\windows\tempDeployment\Logs, but I don't see any filename for that Task Sequence. I did set it to Continue on Error.

Instead of embedding the variable using only one percent sign, try setting the file path as a variable. I.e., $filepath = "$env:DeploymentRoot" + "\Scripts\certs\cert1.cer". Also use Write-Host to log that to a file, and figure out where your task sequences logs are on the client (probably C:\Windows\CCM\Logs).

I had changed the script to just go to folder and install, but didn't work. In the PS1 I  added the lines Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted z: cd Scripts\certs then I changed the instruction to Import-Certificate -FilePath "cert1.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\My

Can't find the log file on the images machine. While it was on the last steps before the last restart I ran the same commands on PS and it installed.

Under c:\windows\tempDeploymentLogs I don't see the task I created for the certs.
